# Automatically merge session user in Symfony2

Tags: security, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have written my own User-class extending Symfony's `UserInterface` and `EquatableInterface` which gets authenticated nice on logins and is correctly retrievable using `$this->getUser();` in a controller.

Now, my question is, if it is possible to write something (dunno, a listener for example) that can automatically merge the user coming from the open session (so the one you retrieve with `$user = $this->getUser();`), so I dont have to call stuff like:

```
/**
 * @Route("/url/to/route")
 */
public function myAction()
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $mergedUser = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->merge($user);
    return array('user' => $mergedUser);
}
```

But instead:

```
/**
 * @Route("/url/to/route")
 */
public function myAction()
{
    /* User gets merged automatically! */
    $mergedUser = $this->getUser();
    return array('user' => $mergedUser);
}
```

Comment: I'd like to see more code on how you've made your own User-class... not a lot of context for us to help you yet. But I'd imagine you'd write your own `getMergedUser()` function that could achieve that every time..

Comment: well, the biggest problem I have in that case that I can't use my merged user in a twig layout. The unmerged `app.user` has not any entities in the one-to-many, many-to-one etc. relations